# iOS : UILabel multiple lines - second line of label needs to start with 10 pixels

Tags: ios

[image]

I am facing one issue that is - I have one label like "1. The Seibl is a software made by the some company and can be purchased at $500"

When it comes to iPhone 4s, the label is printing second line and second line is starting exactly under "1.". I would like to give space/margin/space so that label looks like numbering format.

Comment: if not worked with UILable then i suggest you to use UITextView insted of UILable and set text inset with uitextview like
`textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this solution. It might helps you.

Use an `NSAttributedString` for your label, and set the [`headIndent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSParagraphStyle/headIndent) of its [paragraph style](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/#//apple_ref/c/data/NSParagraphStyleAttributeName):

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
style.headIndent = 14;
NSDictionary *attributes = @{
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style
};
NSAttributedString *richText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"So this UILabel walks into a bar…" attributes:attributes];
self.narrowLabel.attributedText = richText;
self.wideLabel.attributedText = richText;
```

Result:

[image: example result]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at using a `TextView` instead, and modifying its `textStorage` property to define an exclusion area so that a new line is inset. Here's a link to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextStorage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextStorage/addLayoutManager:).